# ng-src in iframe is not working

Tags: angularjs

I am using

```
<div ng-controller="DailyReportsController">
     <iframe ng-src="{{content}}" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe>
</div>
```

to include 'pdf' file in html page. The corresponding controller is given below

```
mainApp.controller('DailyReportsController',
        ['$scope', '$state', '$rootScope', 'mainWebService', '$http', '$sce',
         function($scope, $state, $rootScope, mainWebService, $http, $sce) {

        angular.element(document).ready( function() {
                var drtab = new Royal_Tab($('.dailyrpts_tabs.royal_tab'));
                $scope.content =$sce.trustAsResourceUrl("https://gcc.geojit.net/researchdesk/OPTION STRATEGIES2.pdf");

}
]);
```

But following error raises

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined
at La (http://localhost:8080/flipxl/scripts/angular.min.js:142:109)
at Object.Kb.$set (http://localhost:8080/flipxl/scripts/angular.min.js:65:380)
at Object.fn (http://localhost:8080/flipxl/scripts/angular.min.js:63:358)
at k.$digest (http://localhost:8080/flipxl/scripts/angular.min.js:109:172)
at k.$apply (http://localhost:8080/flipxl/scripts/angular.min.js:112:173)
at h (http://localhost:8080/flipxl/scripts/angular.min.js:72:454)
at w (http://localhost:8080/flipxl/scripts/angular.min.js:77:347)
at XMLHttpRequest.z.onreadystatechange (http://localhost:8080/flipxl/scripts/angular.min.js:78:420)
```

Have any solution please share with me

Comment: well, the error seems to be somewhere else, since the code you showed doesn't have 'nodeName' variable mentioned anywhere.

Comment: should it be `<iframe ng-src="content" ` without `{{..}}`?

Comment: @simoco No that won't work `ng-src` just makes sure that the src attribute is added after the bindings have been resolved. So that you don't get a 404 because of `{{placeholder}}` in your url.

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly fine for me when adding a `$scope.$apply` because of the `ready` event and fixing the missing braces ([**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/7jKKD541nF5sikMt2R63?p=preview), iframes unfortunately don't seem to work in SO snippets).

I was not able to reproduce your error though.

```js
mainApp.controller('DailyReportsController', 
  ['$scope', '$state', '$rootScope', 'mainWebService', '$http', '$sce', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $sce) {
  angular.element(document).ready( function() {
    //var drtab = new Royal_Tab($('.dailyrpts_tabs.royal_tab'));
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.content = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("https://gcc.geojit.net/researchdesk/OPTION STRATEGIES2.pdf");
    });
  });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use directive feature for this as below.

```
var ngApp = angular.module("ngApp",[]);

ngApp.directive("pdfLoader",function(){

  return function(scope,elem,attr){
    elem.append("<object width='100%' height='100%' src='"+ scope.content +"'  type='application/pdf'></object>");
  };

});

ngApp.controller("ngCtrl",function($scope){

  $scope.content ="https://gcc.geojit.net/researchdesk/OPTION STRATEGIES2.pdf"; 

});
```

and html like below

```
<div style="height:100%" pdf-loader></div>
```

Take a look at running example for this at http://jsbin.com/quzoyiloke , And code at http://jsbin.com/quzoyiloke/3/edit?html,js

You can also try by creating new html file whose content is as following.

```html
<html  ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.8/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive("pdfLoader",function(){
  
  return function(scope,elem,attr){
      
    elem.append("<object width='100%' height='100%' src='"+ scope.content +"'  type='application/pdf'></object>");
  };
  
});

myApp.controller("ngCtrl",function($scope){

  $scope.content ="https://gcc.geojit.net/researchdesk/OPTION STRATEGIES2.pdf"; 

});


</script>
</head>
<body ng-app="ngCtrl">
<div ng-controller="ngCtrl">
 <div style="height:100%" pdf-loader></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but it is not working in my application and also in http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/9532/

Comment: You might not able to view output in jsbin because it is not able to load pdf in it's test environment. However you can test by creating html file.